# Does Vim load plugins after loading vimrc?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to override the highlight set in a plugin. The plugin does this:

```
highlight! link WordUnderTheCursor Underlined
```

Firstly, I'm not aware that `!` added to `highlight` does anything. But that's irrelevant.

Doing stuff like this in the vimrc

```
highlight clear WordUnderTheCursor                             
highlight WordUnderTheCursor cterm=bold ctermfg=254 ctermbg=160
```

Does not appear to affect the behavior.

Only when I directly modify the `Underlined` style (which feels wrong) in the vimrc, does the change apply.

Is this proof that the plugin is being run *after* the vimrc runs?

How might I unlink the style? I can't really tell if this is just the plugin doing something creative and unsupported, or if this is normal Vim behavior.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes. vimrc is loaded before plugins.

If you look at [`:h initialization`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#initialization) you will find that step 3 is load vimrc and step 4 is load plugins.

You can also see that vimrc is loaded before plugins by looking at the output of `:scriptnames`. scriptnames lists all sourced scripts in the order they were sourced and vimrc is the first thing sourced. (Take a look at [`:h :scriptnames`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#%3ascriptnames)).

---

To fix the highlighting you just need to run the highlight commands after the plugin gets sourced. To do this you put files in the `after` directory of your `.vim` directory. (Take a look at [`:h after-directory`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#after-directory))

So create the file `.vim/after/plugin/hicursorwords.vim` with the following contents

```
highlight clear WordUnderTheCursor                             
highlight WordUnderTheCursor cterm=bold ctermfg=254 ctermbg=160
```

This will cause the plugin to be sourced before you change the settings of the plugin.

(This of course assumes you don't want to edit the plugin)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I already have a few `after` scripts that override syntax settings so this fits nicely into that whole scheme.

Comment: Be aware that the `_gvimrc` (for graphical purpose) is read _after_ the plugins. You therefore have to enter the commands to be token in consideration in a plugin in a _vimrc and not _gvimrc.

Answer (score 12):

Besides *scriptnames*, to see what order vim runs things in on startup, you can *also* use:

`vim --startuptime <file>`

so it will log all the tasks it does in order, and how much time each one takes.