# Calling Vim plugin command in autocmd fails with E488: Trailing characters

Tags: vim

Need some help on this to explain why I can't call a Plugin command from `autocmd` in VIM:

```
autocmd! Syntax * if !empty(&l:filetype) | RainbowToggleOn | endif
```

Vim detects a syntax error with:

```
Error detected while processing Syntax Auto commands for "*":
E488: Trailing characters:  RainbowToggleOn | endif
```

Comment: mmm, no trailing characters there apparently, and I can't reproduce this error with this line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue caused by a reversed loading order. For some reason my `autocmd` in `vimrc` is running before the plugin is loaded. My guess is that it has something to do with the way `Rainbow.vim` is structured.

According to this answer the loading order is correct: [Does Vim load plugins after loading vimrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688232/does-vim-load-plugins-after-loading-vimrc)

So I was able to solve by delaying the ref lookup of the command:

```
autocmd! Syntax * if !empty(&l:filetype) | exec 'RainbowToggleOn' | endif
```