# reusing earlier inoremap sequence in newer inoremap sequence

Tags: vim

I'm using a plugin that performs multiple `*noremap` operations in its initialization. After I added the following mapping to YCM/UltiSnips:

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? "<C-R>=<SID>ExpandSnippetOrReturn()<CR>" : "\<CR>"
```

I've broken the other plugin's ability to see the `<Enter>` key, or rather I overrode/destroyed the original inoremap. I want to reenable that functionality, but without disabling ability to pick snippets from the auto-complete menu using Enter key. This keymap is effectively saying "if the menu is visible, select the option, otherwise simulate `<Enter>` key". What I need it to say instead is "if the menu is visible, select the option, otherwise perform whatever command `<Enter>` key is already mapped to". So basically, at the time of declaration of this inoremap, I need to expand existing inoremap for this key into the else.

I've looked at `<C-R>=feedkeys('<CR>')<CR>` and `<C-R>=mapcheck('\<CR>', 'i')<CR>` but couldn't get either to work. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out... this was way more vim troubleshooting than I needed for one day.

```
function! LoadPumvisibleEnter()
    let smartmap = maparg("<Enter>", "i")
    execute printf('inoremap <script> <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? "<C-R>=<SID>ExpandSnippetOrReturn()<CR>" : %s', smartmap)
endfunction
au VimEnter * :execute LoadPumvisibleEnter()
```

- throwing it in a function allowed me to stay sane with escapes and which mode I was in
- autocommand is needed because vim apparently runs vimrc BEFORE loading any plugins ([Does Vim load plugins after loading vimrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688232/does-vim-load-plugins-after-loading-vimrc)), so without it the map will not yet be set

Comment: I'd put this as a map inside .vim/after/plugin/<name-of-plugin-that-maps-CR> because it's really not necessary for this to be an autocommand that repeatedly sets a map.

Comment: The mapped functionality is not part of the plugin, it's part of my vim config that I wish to work without breaking existing plugin mapping. Bundling it with the original plugin (which I don't maintain nor wish to fork/maintain) is not a clean solution. Should I choose to switch that plugin out in the future, I don't want the ExpandSnippet mapping to disappear.  Nor do I want the plugin to break if I remove ExpandSnippet function from my vimrc.

Comment: Steven Lu's comment is right. The _after_ directory can be anywhere in your `'runtimepath'`, it doesn't need to be next to the plugin. It's cleaner than using `VimEnter`. Alternatively, you could also `:runtime plugin/original.vi` in your `.vimrc` and then do the remapping right there.