# How to set a VimScript to be executed last?

Tags: vim, configuration, config, configuration-files, macvim

### Problem

A setting in my `vimrc` (`set noshowmode`) is being overridden by a plugin later in the loading process.

### Goal

Have a VimScript file be executed last (or at least after plugins).

### What I Know

- Plugin VimScripts are executed after the `vimrc` ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688232/does-vim-load-plugins-after-loading-vimrc)).
- The `after-directory` is run close to last and holds user overrides
  (Source: `:h after-directory`).
- Vim's `runtimepath` determines the order of what is run.

### Failed Attempts

1. I tried appending a VimScript file (containing `set noshowmode`) to the 
   end of `$VIMRUNTIME` with
   `set runtimepath=$VIMRUNTIME,~/.vim/nosmd.vim`, but this method ended up 
   messing up other plugins (namely `vim-airline`, which did not load).
2. I also tried creating the `~/.vim/after` directory and putting my 
   VimScript in there, but this had no effect.

Comment: `~/.vim/after/plugin/myplugin.vim` should work.

Comment: Is it really overwritten by a plugin? Or is it a ftplugin, or an autoload plugin, or something else (mapping/abbreviation/autocommand)?

Comment: @LucHermitte I haven't put anything in the `ftplugin` directory, and the few autoloads that I have worked nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your attempts

> ```
> set runtimepath=$VIMRUNTIME,~/.vim/nosmd.vim
> ```

That cannot work. `'runtimepath'` contains a list of root configuration directories; you cannot directly place script files in there. Instead, point to a directory that contains `plugin/yours.vim`.

> I also tried creating the `~/.vim/after` directory and putting my VimScript in there, but this had no effect.

You can check with `:scriptnames` to see whether your script was executed (and at the end of the plugin load sequence!)

#### Solutions

An ounce of prevention is better than any workaround. I would first try to locate the culprit who changes the `'showmode'` option; a plugin shouldn't do this (or at least have a configurable option to disable it).

```
:verbose set showmode?
```

might already tell you who changed this setting.

---

As @romainl already commented, `~/.vim/after/plugin/myplugin.vim` should work for undoing this. If it doesn't try the following autocmd (in your `~/.vimrc`) as a last resort:

```
autocmd VimEnter * set noshowmode
```